# Software installation trouble with Homebrew

Tags: osx, directory-structure, cmake, homebrew

I have previously custom installed Python and Homebrew on my OS X 10.9.5 system.
I am now trying to install CMake and I am running into various errors such as:

```
cd: /usr/local/src: No such file or directory
```

and when trying to perform `brew update`, `brew doctor` reports many errors such as:

```
Warning: The /usr/local directory is not writable.

Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar

Python

Warning: You have uncommitted modifications to Homebrew
```

How can I fix these issues or is it preferable to just start from scratch and redo everything? If so, how is this done?

I have a very poor understanding of unix installation and I suspect I have done something wrong causing things to break down somewhere.

Comment: Have you installed a custom Python in /usr/local with the same version as the system Python? Try to remove it (or at least remove `/usr/local/bin/python` if available, it looks like that gets in the way of starting brew.

Answer (score 0):

There is some conflict in the directory is the reason for the cause.

$ /opt/cmake/bin/cmake -version

With the help of the above command you can try whether the Cmake has downloaded properly or not. Else try installing in different location.